# fscanf and fgets giving an incomplete read from virtual serial-port device

Tags: matlab, serial-port, fgets, scanf

I am using matlab to read the output from a serial-port device. When I run the command `fscanf`or `fgets` and it reads the device properly it comes out as:

```
!b,    3,-1532,  -91, -159, -446, -996, 444, 488, 454,5050#
```

When it doesn't it spits out some incomplete read-out such as:

```
, 454,5050#
```

or

```
50, -992, 444, 488, 454,5050#
```

I am not sure what the problem might be such that the read-out is incomplete. Could it be the device settings are not set properly. I am using these commands in a loop to get an on-line reading and when the read-out is incomplete the whole script crashes. Can be very frustrating. Help please =)

EDIT: sample code used to measure

```
`set(glove, 'InputBuffersize', 128); 
 set(glove, 'FlowControl', 'none');
 set(glove, 'BaudRate', 115200);
 set(glove, 'Parity', 'none');
 set(glove, 'DataBits', 8);
 set(glove, 'stopBit', 1);
 set(glove, 'Timeout',100);

 disp(get(glove,'Name'));
 prop(1)=(get(glove,'BaudRate'));
 prop(2)=(get(glove,'DataBits'));
 prop(3)=(get(glove, 'StopBit'));
 prop(4)=(get(glove, 'InputBufferSize'));

 disp([num2str(prop)]);

 fopen(glove);

 test = fgets(glove);

 fclose(glove);`
```

Comment: Show the exact code you're using to read the output - also, is the output at a very high rate?

Comment: The device generates 37 lines per second. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I added the code I am using to read out. I am getting incomplete results just from this simple code.

Comment: It may also depend on what else you're doing in the loop - parsing etc. - and whether that's sufficiently fast to keep up with your serial device. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330121/